# In GTK4 template, how can the limits be set for a spin button?

Tags: templates, gtk4

Simple questionL in a program using GTK4, how can I set the limits for a spin button in the template file? The doc does not list a property or attribute that seems related. There is a method set_range() so I can do it programaticly, but I'm sure there has to be a way to do it in the template file - right?

Answer (score 0):

To set limits for a `GtkSpinButton`, you can override the `adjustment` property with the desired values.

A minimal spin button window with `adjustment` set in the ui file (not a template, so that it works with `gtk4-builder-tool preview`):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <object class="GtkWindow">
    <child>
      <object class="GtkSpinButton" id="button">
        <property name="adjustment">
          <object class="GtkAdjustment">
            <property name="lower">3</property>
            <property name="value">3</property>
            <property name="step-increment">2</property>
            <property name="upper">19</property>
          </object>
        </property>
      </object>  <!-- ./GtkSpinButton button -->
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

To run, do `gtk4-builder-tool  preview spin.ui`.  To reduce some clutter, you can also define the class between `</template>` and `</interface>` and use the `adjustment` for the spin button, Eg.:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <template class="SpinWindow" parent="GtkWindow">
    <child>
      <object class="GtkSpinButton" id="age_spin_button">
        <property name="adjustment">age_adjustment</property>
      </object>
    </child>
  </template>

  <object class="GtkAdjustment" id="age_adjustment">
    <property name="lower">1</property>
    <property name="value">18</property>
    <property name="step-increment">1</property>
    <property name="upper">200</property>
  </object>

</interface>
```